# Using reflection to access some fields in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, reflection

I have a class `BaseDialog extends DialogFragment`

After a while, i found out that the default DialogFragment.show() can cause some problems - if the activity is being shutdown, or destroyed etc...

After looking at the decompiled(?) source of DialogFragment, i stumble on this piece of code:

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

And i figure to try a small 'hack' of my own to get rid of bugs relating to showing/dismissing dialogs after Activity has passed it's `onSaveInstanceState()` call.

I came up with this:

```
public void showAllowingStateLoss(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
        Class thiz = super.getClass();
        Field dismissed = thiz.getField("mDismissed");
        dismissed.setAccessible(true);
        dismissed.set(thiz, false);
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mDismissed = false;

    try {
        Class thiz = super.getClass();
        Field shown = thiz.getField("mShownByMe");
        shown.setAccessible(true);
        shown.set(thiz, true);
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mShownByMe = true;

    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Which works quite alright.

The problem I have now is this, i can't seem to access some of DialogFragment's fields to set them to their proper expected values like the original source does.

```
W/System.err( 2510): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mDismissed
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1048)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:70)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.openConfirmationDialog(ActivityLogin.java:250)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.access$600(ActivityLogin.java:45)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:306)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:262)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.backend.soap.SOAPHelper$20.onPostExecute(SOAPHelper.java:1290)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
W/System.err( 2510): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mShownByMe
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1048)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:81)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.openConfirmationDialog(ActivityLogin.java:250)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.access$600(ActivityLogin.java:45)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:306)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:262)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.backend.soap.SOAPHelper$20.onPostExecute(SOAPHelper.java:1290)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
W/System.err( 2510): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mViewDestroyed
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1048)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:95)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.openConfirmationDialog(ActivityLogin.java:250)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin.access$600(ActivityLogin.java:45)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:306)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityLogin$SOAPListener_getUserLogin.onSOAPSuccess(ActivityLogin.java:262)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.dpd.navigator.backend.soap.SOAPHelper$20.onPostExecute(SOAPHelper.java:1290)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err( 2510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err( 2510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

And I'm wondering why can't I access those fields.... they're not static, so getField() should work. I've tried `getDeclaredField()` as well - no dice.

So I'm starting to wonder - is it even feasible to try and access those fields using reflection? I know that some Android code (SDK code) is there "just for show" because we can't touch it - it runs in the `AndroidRuntime` process which is why reflection can't do anything there.

Which is why i'm asking the question: am I not finding these fields because they're running in the AndroidRuntime process OR because i'm doing something wrong?

I can live with the first case. I would really like to set them to their expected values if it's the second case.

P.S. I'm really not interested in preachings about why using `commitAllowingStateLoss` is wrong and/or bad. The focus of the question isn't that. **The focus of the question is why can't I find these fields?**

Thanks for help in advance :)

EDIT:
Here's the logcat to show that using `getDeclaredField` doesn't work either.

```
W/System.err(  330): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mDismissed
W/System.err(  330):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:886)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:70)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityMenu.openProfile(ActivityMenu.java:275)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityMenu.access$000(ActivityMenu.java:31)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.activities.ActivityMenu$1.onClick(ActivityMenu.java:74)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err(  330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err(  330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(  330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err(  330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

EDIT2:

Thanks to @pskink 's and @derek-fung 's inputs, i changed the code to this:

```
public void showAllowingStateLoss(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
//      Class<? extends DialogFragment> thiz = DialogFragment.class;
        Class<? extends DialogFragment> thiz = ((DialogFragment)this).getClass();
        Field dismissed = thiz.getDeclaredField("mDismissed"); <-- line 71
        dismissed.setAccessible(true);
        dismissed.set(this, false);
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mDismissed = false;

    try {
        Class<? extends DialogFragment> thiz = ((DialogFragment)this).getClass();
//      Field shown = thiz.getField("mShownByMe");
        Field shown = thiz.getDeclaredField("mShownByMe"); <-- line 83
        shown.setAccessible(true);
        shown.set(this, true);
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mShownByMe = true;

    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Using `DialogFragment.class` was causing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type android.app.DialogFragment, but got java.lang.Class<android.app.DialogFragment>` which is why I tried casting it into one.

And the result was:

```
W/System.err( 3227): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mDismissed
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:886)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:71)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.openConfirmationDialog(ActivityDPDSplash.java:636)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.startApplication(ActivityDPDSplash.java:866)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.access$600(ActivityDPDSplash.java:70)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash$7.run(ActivityDPDSplash.java:765)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
W/System.err( 3227): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mShownByMe
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:886)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(BaseDialog.java:83)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.openConfirmationDialog(ActivityDPDSplash.java:636)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.startApplication(ActivityDPDSplash.java:866)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash.access$600(ActivityDPDSplash.java:70)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.dpd.navigator.ActivityDPDSplash$7.run(ActivityDPDSplash.java:765)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
W/System.err( 3227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
W/System.err( 3227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

The thing that did the trick is this:

```
public void showAllowingStateLoss(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
        Class<? extends DialogFragment> thiz = DialogFragment.class;
        Field dismissed = thiz.getDeclaredField("mDismissed");
        dismissed.setAccessible(true);
        dismissed.set(this, false);
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mDismissed = false;

    try {
        Class<? extends DialogFragment> thiz = DialogFragment.class;
        Field shown = thiz.getDeclaredField("mShownByMe");
        shown.setAccessible(true);
        shown.set(this, true);
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //mShownByMe = true;

    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: `getDeclaredField` it works, BTW you are **REALLY** asking for troubles...

Comment: @pskink as i said, both `getField()` and `getDeclaredField()` can't find it. I'll update the post with the logcat to show that i've tried that too.

Comment: http://codeshare.io/1ANhv

Comment: The final edit version solved this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `super.getClass()` with `DialogFragment.class`

together with `getDeclaredField()`

It is because `super.getClass()` would return the class of your instance, instead of your superclass which you want. And `getField()` cannot get `private` field.

**Edit:**

`dismissed.set(thiz, false);` should be replaced with `dismissed.set(this, false);` because you need to provide the object not the class in order to set a field.

Comment: `DialogFragment.getClass()` can't be used becase "A non-static method cannot be accessed from a static context".

Using `DialogFragment.class` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type android.app.DialogFragment, but got java.lang.Class<android.app.DialogFragment>`

but i'll try something similar, the answer is still useful :)

Comment: you should use `dismissed.set(this, false);` instead of `dismissed.set(thiz, false);`, you need to provide the object not the class

Comment: no dice, same results. I'll update the post with the latest results and the code tried

Comment: you should use DialogFragment.class

Comment: regarding your edit - perhaps that's the reason i got an illegalargumentexception?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException is caused by you used `thiz` in `set`